# generalise where clause in linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-4

I have the following linq query:

```
    var fileDocuments = (
        from doc in fileUploads
        from invoice in
            (
                from inv in _dbContext.SupplierInvoiceHeaders
                where inv.InvoiceDocumentId == doc.ID || inv.JobSheetInvoiceId == doc.ID
                select inv
                ).DefaultIfEmpty()
        join pos in _dbContext.PurchaseOrders on invoice.PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderId equals pos.PurchaseOrderId into poss
        from po in poss.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join hdf in _dbContext.HelpDeskFaults on po.HelpdeskFaultId equals hdf.ID into hdfpo
        from hs in hdfpo.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join store1 in _dbContext.Stores on hs.StoreID equals store1.ID into hsf
        from hdfStore in hsf.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join js in _dbContext.JobSheets on invoice.SupplierInvoiceHeaderId equals js.SupplierInvoiceHeaderID into jss
        from jobSheets in jss.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join ch in _dbContext.ChildProjects on po.ChildProjectId equals ch.ID into chs
        from childProjects in chs.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join ph in _dbContext.ProjectHeaders on childProjects.ProjectHeaderID equals ph.ID into phs
        from projectHeaders in phs.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join ppmsl in _dbContext.PpmScheduleLines on projectHeaders.PPMScheduleRef equals ppmsl.ID into ppsmsls
        from ppmScheduleLines in ppsmsls.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join ss2 in _dbContext.Stores on ppmScheduleLines.StoreID equals ss2.ID into ssts
        from store2 in ssts.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where getJobWhereClause(invoice, hs, ppmScheduleLines, doc) 
        select new
        {
            doc.ID,
            JobSheetId = jobSheets.DocumentID,
            doc.Name,
            doc.DateCreated,
            doc.StoreID,
            StoreName = doc.Store.Name,
            DocumentType = doc.DocumentType.Name,
            doc.DocumentTypeID
        })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Distinct()
        .Select(d => new JobDocumentDto
        {
            ID = d.ID,
            DocumentID = (d.JobSheetId) ?? d.ID,
            DocumentName = d.Name,
            DateCreated = d.DateCreated.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
            StoreName = d.StoreName,
            DocumentTypeName = d.DocumentType,
            DocumentTypeId = d.DocumentTypeID
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);
    return fileDocuments;
```

I have tried to separate the where clause into a func:

```
    Func<SupplierInvoiceHeader, HelpDeskFault, PpmScheduleLineEntity, DocumentUploadEntity, bool> getJobWhereClause = (invoice, helpDeskFault, ppmScheduleLine, doc) =>
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobSearchParams.PIR) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobSearchParams.StoreName))
        {
            return invoice.PurchaseInvoiceReference == jobSearchParams.PIR;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobSearchParams.PIR) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobSearchParams.StoreName))
        {
            return helpDeskFault.Store.Name.Contains(jobSearchParams.StoreName) || doc.Store.Name.Contains(jobSearchParams.StoreName) || ppmScheduleLine.Store.Name.Contains(jobSearchParams.StoreName);     
        }

        return invoice.PurchaseInvoiceReference == jobSearchParams.PIR && (helpDeskFault.Store.Name.Contains(jobSearchParams.StoreName) || doc.Store.Name.Contains(jobSearchParams.StoreName) || ppmScheduleLine.Store.Name.Contains(jobSearchParams.StoreName));
    };
```

I get the following error message:

> Test method
>   IntegrationTests.Services.DocumentUploadServiceTests.Should_Search_By_PIR
>   threw exception:  System.NotSupportedException: The LINQ expression
>   node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Which makes sense because there is no direct translation from the func to sql but is there a way I can create an expression that will achieve what I am after?

Comment: Just declare that variable as Expression<Func<SupplierInvoiceHeader, HelpDeskFault, PpmScheduleLineEntity, DocumentUploadEntity, bool>>, not pure Func

Comment: I've tried that but I get a compiler error for the actual equality checks:

A lambda expression with statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.

Comment: Yes I missed it's not a lambda expression. Can you convert it to single statement with "? :" operator maybe?

Comment: I'd lose readability if I did that.  I need to read up on expression trees

Comment: [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) is what you need

Comment: Well you will lose some readability, but you will lose it much more with pure expression trees. Not sure if LinqKit will help in your case, but if yes then sure go with it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to use an extension method and return an IQueryable, something like this (just fill in the ...):

```
public static IQueryable<fileUpload> FilterByThisStuff(this DbSet<fileUpload> db, ... invoice, ... helpDeskFault, ... ppmScheduleLine, ... doc)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobSearchParams.PIR) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobSearchParams.StoreName))
    {
        return db.Where(invoice=>invoice.PurchaseInvoiceReference == jobSearchParams.PIR);
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobSearchParams.PIR) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobSearchParams.StoreName))
    {
        return db.Where(...);     
    }

    return db.Where(...);
};
```

I've noticed you have an awful lot of joins there.  Consider actually building your model with navigation properties instead.  In anycase you can then use the above just like any other LINQ method, otherwise you will need to make some concrete class so you can use it in the extension method.  The easy way:

```
var results=db.FileUploads
  .FilterByThisStuff(a,b,c,d)
  .Select(...)
  .OrderBy(...)
  .Take(...);
```